# Access UNC path file share from iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, unc, delphi-xe5

Enviroment: Win 7, Delphi XE5 Architect, iOS

I have FireMonkey mobile app that works in LAN with Windows workstations and iOS device. The Windows workstations have shared folders.

The task is to get some files from a workstation to iOS device.

Something like:

```
TFileStream.Create('\\192.168.0.1\c\temp\picture.jpg', fmOpenRead);
```

Have I a chance to get a file?

I have seen some FileBrowsers for iOS. They work with SMB protocol perfectly and I can get any file from any legal share in LAN. So, how can I access file share in FireMonkey?

Comment: From the Mac, with FireMonkey, you'd probably at least access a file like `SMB://host/file`, but iOS doesn't support SMB natively, and at this point, you're relying on the OS, so you'd probably have to roll your own implementation or use third party. This is just speculation, so maybe someone will know a FireMonkey solution.

Comment: @Marcus. Thanks for you answer. Probably you know some solution with Indy components from XE5... Have you an idea?

Comment: You could implement with Indy's TCP client. If you are using Windows Vista or greater Windows PCs, then you have SMB2, which is simple and uses TCP. Microsoft graciously shares SMB2 specs for interoperability: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246482.aspx

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. I think I will use FTP way.